# Convert function to Classic ASP

Tags: date, asp-classic

I am using a mailing list program which inserts a date into a web link that is "encoded" so it can't be changed or edited by users.

The format is described as follows:

> An eight character string, `AABBCCDD,`where:
>
> - Year = `1980 + HexToInt(BB) / 3`
> - Month =  `HexToInt(CC) / 7 - 21`
> - Day = `HexToInt(DD) / 7 - 5`
>
> There is also a checksum included to avoid casual modification:
>
> `AA = IntToHex(Year + Month + Day mod 200)`
>
> For example `2660BDAF` would refer to `20 June, 2012`.

---

Can you help me convert the following to Classic ASP:

```
CodedDateStr = Request.querystring("Exp")
AYear = 1980 + HexToInt(CodedDateStr[3] + CodedDateStr[4]) / 3
AMonth =  HexToInt(CodedDateStr[5] + CodedDateStr[6]) / 7 - 21
ADay =  HexToInt(CodedDateStr[7] + CodedDateStr[8]) / 7 - 5
ACheckSum = AYear + AMonth + ADay mod 200

if ACheckSum <> HexToInt(CodedDateStr[1] + CodedDateStr[2]) then
  ValidDate = 0
else
  ValidDate = 1
end if

AExpiryDate = EncodeDate(ADay, AMonth, AYear)

if Date() > AExpiryDate then
  ExpiredOffer = 1
else
  ExpiredOffer = 0
end if

....
```

It looks like the `HexToInt` equivalent is `clng("&h" & hexnumber)`

I'm not sure about `EncodeDate`, i hope it is not something cludgy like `CDate(AMonth + "/" + ADay + "/" + AYear)`

Comment: mhh this is classic asp?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You'll have a better chance of getting answers if you focus on the specific issues you're having with your conversion.  To that end, what are the functions `HexToInt` and `EncodeDate` supposed to do?  (you should edit your question by using the "edit" link below the tags.

Comment: Sorry, HexToInt should turn a string such as "FF" to the decimal, 255.  EncodeDate should convert a Day, a Month and a year into a date value (for comparison against ASP's Date() function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CLng("&h" & hexnumber)` looks like a good method for HexToInt.

For EncodeDate, look at the [`DateSerial`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1we4t8hy%28VS.84%29.aspx) function, which takes a year, month, and day, and returns a Date value.